# multiprocessing in python with error 'takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given'

Tags: python, django, process, multiprocessing, queue

)

i'm a beginner in python and django and try to run a external code with multiprocessing.

On my first try import a .txt with numpy, my code runs. 
On my second try to import a .csv with pandas, i get an error message.
What is the different? Why doesn't run the second try?

**quick.py**

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def import_txt(q, w_url):
    w_data = np.loadtxt(w_url,delimiter=';', dtype='str')
    q.put(w_data)

def import_csv(q, w_url):
    w_data = pd.read_csv(w_url)
    w_data.head()
    q.put(True)
```

**views.py**

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue, set_start_method
from app.static.code.quick import import_txt as q_txt
from app.static.code.quick import import_csv as q_csv
```

**this works**

```
def q_history(request):

    if request.method == 'POST' and request.is_ajax():

        #erstellt den pfad
        m_user = request.user.username
        m_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
        m_dir = os.path.join(m_dir, 'app', 'media', m_user, 'quick', 'ini.txt')

        set_start_method('spawn', True)
        q = Queue()
        p = Process(target=q_txt, args=(q,m_dir))
        p.start()
        m_data = q.get()
        p.join()      

        return JsonResponse(m_data.tolist(), safe=False)

    else :
        assert isinstance(request, HttpRequest)
        return render(
        request,
        'quick.html',
        {
            'title':'title',
            'message':'Your application description page.',
            'year':datetime.now().year,
        }
    )
```

**this not**

```
def q_csv(request):

    if request.method == 'POST' and request.is_ajax():

        #erstellt den pfad
        m_user = request.user.username
        m_file = '2019_Test.csv'
        m_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
        m_dir = os.path.join(m_dir, 'app', 'media', m_user, 'quick', 'input', m_file)

        set_start_method('spawn', True)
        q = Queue()
        p = Process(target=q_csv, args=(q,m_dir))
        p.start()
        m_data = q.get()
        p.join()      

        return JsonResponse(m_data.tolist(), safe=False)

    else :
        assert isinstance(request, HttpRequest)
        return render(
        request,
        'quick.html',
        {
            'title':'title',
            'message':'Your application description page.',
            'year':datetime.now().year,
        }
    )
```

**Error**

```
Process Process-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.4/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 297, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.4/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 99, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
TypeError: q_csv() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With this line:

```
p = Process(target=q_csv, args=(q,m_dir))
```

you are calling this method

```
def q_csv(request):
```

with 2 parameters (`q` and `m_dir`) but it only takes 1 (`request`), I think you probably just want to name your function q_csv differently because I guess that you want the one from the imports. So change the line

```
def q_csv(request):
```

to

```
def q_csv_processing(request):
```

and see if it gets you what you want to achieve.

Comment: Wow, thank you for your feedback.

You are right, both functions have the same names. 
i didn't see this, after hours of coding and testing.

Answer (score 0):

If you are having this issue when the function takes a single argument and you are passing a single argument, then likely you have syntactical issue.

Let's assume you have the following function

```
def task(param: str):
  # do something
```

and if you are defining

```
p = multiprocessing.Process(target=task, args=("ab"))
```

This will tell you

```
TypeError: task() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

**What is the issue here??**

Well, the constructor argument `args` must be a `tuple`. When you have a single element inside the parenthesis, python considers the parenthesis to be a syntactical sugar and ignores them!

You pass a string, which also iterable. It says two arguments were passed because this is the number of characters inside the string `ab`.

```
type(("ab")) # prints str
type(("ab",)) # prints tuple
```

So simply add a comma to explicitly indicate that you want to construct a tuple!

```
p = multiprocessing.Process(target=task, args=("ab",))
```